# Select rows in DataFrame if value in any column is between two values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have looked this up and I think what I have should work, but it isn't. The first condition (>= 80) is being evaluated but the second (<= 100) is not.

I want every row in which ANY column value is between 80 and 100 inclusive, BUT, if any column value is greater than 100 then exclude it.

I should only see the rows AP-2, AP-8 and AP-9.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'AP-1': [30, 32, 34, 31, 33, 35, 36, 38, 37],
                   'AP-2': [30, 32, 34, 80, 33, 35, 36, 38, 37],
                   'AP-3': [30, 32, 81, 31, 33, 101, 36, 38, 37],
                   'AP-4': [30, 32, 34, 95, 33, 35, 103, 38, 121],
                   'AP-5': [30, 32, 34, 31, 33, 144, 36, 38, 37],
                   'AP-6': [30, 32, 34, 31, 33, 35, 36, 110, 37],
                   'AP-7': [30, 87, 34, 31, 111, 35, 36, 38, 122],
                   'AP-8': [30, 32, 99, 31, 33, 35, 36, 38, 37],
                   'AP-9': [30, 32, 34, 31, 33, 99, 88, 38, 37]}, index=['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'])


df1 = df.transpose()

print(df1)
print()

df2 = df1[(df1.values >= 80).any(1) & (df1.values <= 100).any(1)]

print(df2)
```

df2 is coming out as:

       `1   2   3   4    5    6    7    8    9
AP-2  30  32  34  80   33   35   36   38   37
AP-3  30  32  81  31   33  101   36   38   37
AP-4  30  32  34  95   33   35  103   38  121
AP-5  30  32  34  31   33  144   36   38   37
AP-6  30  32  34  31   33   35   36  110   37
AP-7  30  87  34  31  111   35   36   38  122
AP-8  30  32  99  31   33   35   36   38   37
AP-9  30  32  34  31   33   99   88   38   37`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is another idea, separate the masks and use & to join:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'AP-1': [30, 32, 34, 31, 33, 35, 36, 38, 37],
                   'AP-2': [30, 32, 34, 80, 33, 35, 36, 38, 37],
                   'AP-3': [30, 32, 81, 31, 33, 101, 36, 38, 37],
                   'AP-4': [30, 32, 34, 95, 33, 35, 103, 38, 121],
                   'AP-5': [30, 32, 34, 31, 33, 144, 36, 38, 37],
                   'AP-6': [30, 32, 34, 31, 33, 35, 36, 110, 37],
                   'AP-7': [30, 87, 34, 31, 111, 35, 36, 38, 122],
                   'AP-8': [30, 32, 99, 31, 33, 35, 36, 38, 37],
                   'AP-9': [30, 32, 34, 31, 33, 99, 88, 38, 37]}, 
                   index=['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'])

# This is the actual frame you want
df = df.transpose()

m1 = (df >= 80).any(1) 
m2 = ~(df >= 100).any(1) #<-- Invert the statement with ~

df2 = df.loc[m1&m2]
print(df2)
```

Prints:

```
      1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
AP-2  30  32  34  80  33  35  36  38  37
AP-8  30  32  99  31  33  35  36  38  37
AP-9  30  32  34  31  33  99  88  38  37
```

Comment: Thank you.  I am quite new to pandas and had never seen an implementation like the one you present here.  I think I like yours better.

Comment: @MarkS It is a matter of preference how you write your code. I however prefer more rows than less (think it is more clear that way).

Comment: Is there a reason you went with m2 = ~(df >= 100).any(1) as opposed to m2 = (df <= 100).all(1) ?

Comment: @MarkS Mostly because how **you** formulated the problem: `if any column value is greater than 100 then exclude it.`

Comment: Oh, I think I see.  While equivalent in the results they produce, over a large data set yours probably runs faster since .any would terminate quicker.  .all would have to check every column every time, .any would find one instance that violates my requirement and opt out right then and there.

Comment: @MarkS Yes that is true

Answer (score 1):

Ah, I got it.  I needed .all(1) for the <= 100.